# TextChanged event not fring

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have connected the textbox to the textchanged event, enabled AutoPostBack and disabled AutoComplete.  When i check the code it says that there is no references.  The autopostback and autocomplete ideas came from previously asked questions.

This is the textbox source code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtProjectName" runat="server" Width="215px" OnTextChanged="TxtProjectName_TextChanged" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is the event code

```
 protected void TxtProjectName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TxtProjectName.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            txtProjectDescription.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (TxtProjectName.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            txtProjectDescription.Text = "";
            txtProjectDescription.Enabled = false;

        }
    }
```

This is a simple test website i am building, it is my first day with ASP.Net. I have a basic understand of c# in general

Anyone have any ideas what the problem could be?

*Update, debugging shows that it is firing the event, however, it does not

Comment: `When i check the code it says that there is no references.` What does this mean?

Comment: the little bit above the event code

Comment: 0 references | 0 Exceptions

Comment: I pasted that code on a page and it's working. The question would be, when do you expect that event to be executed?

Comment: Is it actually posting back?

Comment: The event will be executed when the text has changed in the textbox, then enabling the other textbox.

Comment: @SpookiBear the event is exectuted on **postback** and only if the user changed the value. This is not winforms.

Comment: You have connected the textbox to the TextChanged event and not click event(as you mention in ur description). Are you trying to postback on click of a button if so. then you have to have the code behind attached to ur button and not the textbox. The event wil now only trigger if you write something in the textbox.

Comment: Please give us a clear and concise statement, what is happening and what you expect to happen. If you receive errors, add the error message to your question. Sentences like "debugging shows that it is firing the event, however, it does not" do not help in the slightest.

Comment: sorry Mikhaeljan, I meant to say textChanged event, thats for pointing that out.  It was a typo.  Yes it already is connected a textchanged event

Comment: @SpookiBear, what are the names of the .aspx and the .cs files where the above code exists? It might be better to show the whole .aspx and .cs code files in your question. What you have shown above, works, it will be what else you have done that will be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to write that logic in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the "0 references" message attached to your method definition only counts references to that method in your C# code (in the case of VS 2017 at least), not any ASPX code. I just took a look through any ASP.NET webforms code that I had on hand and it seems like all of my ASPX event handler methods (in C# codebehinds) have a "0 references" message attached to them, except in the rare event I've explicitly called them from my other custom C# code. Even with the "0 references" message these handler methods are still working as expected.